# Copy site from webserver to localhost

Tags: database, installation

I've had no joy using Akeeba and Kickstart (current versions). The restore locks up on the last screen when it tried to update .htaccess

I've set up a new joomla site, and loaded my critical website templates & other extensions, with everything working. I have a copy of the database, but I don't know how to load it in.

a. Would you please offer advice on how to do this?
b. If this is successful, is there something else I'll need to do?

Many thanks

Comment: How do you know it locked up trying to update .htaccess? Is there an error message?

Comment: Neil - yes there's error message. @jazzzbo you really can ignore it. I don't know why it happens in last version by I'm ignoring it and just closing current tab and clicking clean up on the next one and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

I did this a couple of times, my setup differs surely from yours, but this is how I imported the database. I assume you are using MySQL as database.

1. first make sure that the database and PHP is the same version (webserver/localhost)
2. the information for the database setup you will find in the file "configuration.php" in the root folder of your Joomla site
3. the following lines are important (adjust to fit your setup)

   ```
   public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
   public $host ='localhost';
   public $user = 'root';
   public $password = 'some_password';
   public $db = 'some_db';
   public $dbprefix = 'prefix_';
   ```
4. save and quit the file
5. create the database, preferably in a terminal

   ```
   terminal> mysql -u root -p"your_password"
   mysql> create database "db_name"; (same as in config)
   mysql>exit
   ```
6. now import the database, using the terminal again

   here is an example:

   ```
   terminal> mysql -u root -p"your_password" name_of_the_database < your_database_file.sql
   ```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I finally got the site transferred. It appears that the backup software had a glitch that was repaired in the latest release. Running it enabled everything to work as before.